# Is this a bug in auto arima or am I doing something wrong?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I must be doing something very wrong here, as auto.arima in R is completely dying, but I can't see what it is.  I have the latest version of forecast and R and I think this happens on both Windows and Unix.  It works for some/most time series I tried (equities) but fails for others.  It seems to fail more often when I diff the high/low with the previous day's close as opposed to just diffing the closes as below.  Is this a bug or am I somehow giving arima bad data? (and causing it to die with a horrible error message)  I tried searching for this error but didn't come up with much.  Thanks a lot.

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
dwa <- get.hist.quote(instrument="DWA", start="2010-01-01", end="2013-10-31")
logreturns <- diff(log(dwa$Close))*100 
fit <- auto.arima(logreturns, trace=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
This is forecast 4.8 

trying URL 'http://chart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=DWA&a=0&b=01&c=2010&d=9&e=31&f=2013&g=d&q=q&y=0&z=DWA&x=.csv'
Content type 'text/csv' length unknown
opened URL
.......... .......... .......... .......... ....
downloaded 44 Kb

time series starts 2010-01-04
time series ends   2013-10-07

 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(1,1,2) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(3,1,2) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(2,1,3) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(3,1,3) with drift         : 1e+20 *
 ARIMA(2,1,2)          : 1e+20 *Error in if (diffs == 1 & constant) { : argument is of length zero
Calls: auto.arima -> myarima
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In if (is.constant(x)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (is.constant(x)) return(d) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (is.constant(dx)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Execution halted
```

Comment: The AIC values are abnormally high, so I would suspect bad data.

Comment: As @forecaster has pointed out, the problem is that `auto.arima` expects a `ts` object, not a `zoo` object. However, the error message is very unfriendly. I'll catch it more cleanly in the next version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Aaron, your timeseries data is discontinous. auto.arima as many other forecast methods in R requires equally spaced time series.

The problem is your time series is not equally spaced, meaning there are gaps in the dates.

The following code converts the time series into a vector, and now the auto.arima works fine.

If you have seasonality in the data and you might want to clean the dataset and make it equally spaced time series.

```
library(tseries)
library(forecast)
dwa <- get.hist.quote(instrument="DWA", start="2010-01-01", end="2013-10-31")
logreturns <- diff(log(dwa$Close))*100
logreturns_nots = unclass(logreturns) ## converst time series into a vector.
fit <- auto.arima(logreturns_nots, trace=TRUE)
```

following is the result:

```
 ARIMA(2,1,2) with drift         : 4206.508
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : 4849.189
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : 4567.961
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : 1e+20
 ARIMA(1,1,2) with drift         : 1e+20
 ARIMA(3,1,2) with drift         : 4196.642
 ARIMA(3,1,1) with drift         : 4204.641
 ARIMA(3,1,3) with drift         : 1e+20
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : 4213.613
 ARIMA(4,1,3) with drift         : 1e+20
 ARIMA(3,1,2)                    : 4194.541
 ARIMA(2,1,2)                    : 4204.487
 ARIMA(4,1,2)                    : 1e+20
 ARIMA(3,1,1)                    : 4202.653
 ARIMA(3,1,3)                    : 1e+20
 ARIMA(2,1,1)                    : 4211.68
 ARIMA(4,1,3)                    : 1e+20

 Best model: ARIMA(3,1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  I will look into cleaning/deseasonalizing as you suggest.  I am trying to learn about this stuff.